# ssl domain problem for signed asterisk certificates

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have two hosts set on apache server with signed ssl certs.
Both virtual hosts have correct configuration I believe. 
First is sub.domain.com witch is working correctly and browsers don't complain for its cert.
Second domain is level.sub.domain.com and it generating errors,
what I get is ssl_error_bad_cert_domain for

> level.sub.domain.com uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is only valid for the following names:   *.domain.com
>   , domain.com

Should the *.domain.com certificate support more than one level subdomain?

Answer (score 3):

*.domain.com should only match for domains .domain.com, but not domain.com or a.b.domain.com.

Citing this [great presentation](https://www.switch.ch/pki/meetings/2007-01/namebased_ssl_virtualhosts.pdf):

> RFC 2595 (Using TLS with IMAP, POP3 and ACAP): A “*” wildcard character MAY be used as the
>   left-most name component in the certificate. For example, *.example.com would match
>   a.example.com, foo.example.com, etc. but would not match example.com.
>
> RFC 2818 (HTTP Over TLS): Names may contain the wildcard character * which is considered to
>   match any single domain name component or component fragment. E.g., *.a.com matches
>   foo.a.com but not bar.foo.a.com. f*.com matches foo.com but not bar.com.
>
> RFC 4513 (LDAP Authentication Methods): The ‘*’ (ASCII 42) wildcard character is allowed in
>   subjectAltName values of type dNSName, and then only as the left-most (least significant)
>   DNS label in that value. This wildcard matches any left-most DNS label in the server name.
>   That is, the subject *.example.com matches the server names a.example.com and
>   b.example.com, but does not match example.com or a.b.example.com.