# SSL wildcard certificate + SAN to match multiple specific subdomains of wildcard section

Tags: ssl-certificate, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

Say I own the domain `example.com` and want to setup multiple websites as sub domains on this domain, but these websites also use several special endpoints as further subdomains. Can I put them all on 1 SAN + wildcard SSL certificate, and what providers might support creation of said certificate?

I.e., I would like to protect

```
example.com
siteXXX.example.com (where siteXXX refers to the sub sites token)
www.example.com
api.example.com
mail.example.com
www.siteXXX.example.com
api.siteXXX.example.com
mail.siteXXX.example.com
```

I was thinking I'd need something that looks like

```
example.com
*.example.com (covers siteXXX, api, www, mail)
www.*.example.com (covers www.siteXXX)
api.*.example.com (covers api.siteXXX)
mail.*.example.com (covers mail.siteXXX)
```

Does the standard even allow this? I'm not sure because I can only find example with the wildcard component as the lowest level sub domain, not a mid level sub domain.

Comment: Nope, can't do that. Why not generate each site with it's own San?

Comment: Or `www-sitexxx`

Comment: Mostly dupe https://serverfault.com/q/296390/ and https://serverfault.com/q/817255/ and https://serverfault.com/q/871171/

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 No it's, not, all those questions, applied to why wildcard subdomains only matched one level, I was asking if I could have the wildcard component as a non left most segment of the domain name. Zip's answer explains the reason why this wron't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you issue a certificate with those SANs, they would not validate those domains on browsers or any application that follows the best practices for a PKI (read [this RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6.4.3) from the IETF, for example).

You are thinking as a legitimate owner of all the domains covered by that certificate, but what if a browser accepted a certificate for `www.*.com`?

I own `www.zip.com`, but that shouldn't make me able to issue a certificate that would validate `www.amazon.com` too.

Answer (score 0):

A Wildcard SSL certificate covers only the subdomains on the name it's registered to. A `*.domain.com` SSL certificate will cover anything under `domain.com`, but not under the subdomains in `domain.com`. So, it wouldn't cover `second.first.domain.com`.

Although Wildcard Certificates do not cover multiple levels of subdomains, you can add it to the certificate as a SAN. To do this, check with your certificate issuer on how to do this. Most will allow for this. You simply add the subdomain with another asterisk in it. So, I can add a SAN of `*.first.domain.com` to the certificate and that will cover my `second.first.domain.com` domain. It also covers anything under it. And be sure to add the root domain itself, since the Wildcard Certificate **does not** cover it (I think).

So, in response to your question, you can obtain a Wildcard Certificate securing

```
*.domainname.com
```

With SANs of

```
domainname.com
*.siteXXX.domainname.com
```

I hope this helps!